# Is it possible to create composite Primary Keys in Records?

Tags: plugin-development, database, records

I've structured my Record as such:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class MyPlugin_MerchantOrderRecord extends BaseRecord
{
  public function getTableName()
  {
    return 'myplugin_merchant_orders';
  }

  protected function defineAttributes()
  {
    return [
      'merchant_id' => AttributeType::Number,
      'order_id' => AttributeType::Number,
      ...
    ];
  }

  public function primaryKey()
  {
    return ['merchant_id', 'order_id'];
  }

  public function defineRelations()
  {
      return [
        'merchant' => [static::BELONGS_TO, 'MyPlugin_MerchantRecord', 'merchant_id', 
               'required' => true, 'onDelete' => static::CASCADE],
        'order' => [static::BELONGS_TO, 'Commerce_OrderRecord', 'order_id', 
               'required' => true, 'onDelete' => static::CASCADE],
      ];
  }
}
```

When I install the plugin I get the following error:

`Illegal offset type in isset or empty`

If I take away the `primaryKey()` definition, the table is created successfully and the `foreign keys` are in place as expected.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next ([post 2.6.2791](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2791)) release so that plugins can define composite primary keys in their records.

Comment: You boys don't mess around do you! Thanks for the quick turnaround on this, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear not unfortunately.

Craft's `BaseRecord` (which a `Record` should inherit from) tries to uses the `primaryKey()` method call to help create the table, but assumes a single column name is returned, not an Array and so falls over on the `isset` call.

```
$pk = $this->primaryKey();

if (isset($columns[$pk]))
{
  $columns[$pk]['primaryKey'] = true;
  $addIdColumn = false;
}
else
{
  $addIdColumn = true;
}
```

I'm guessing it should work because the `CActiveRecord` (which the `BaseRecord` inherits from) states in it's comments for PrimaryKey:

```
@return mixed the primary key of the associated database table.

If the key is a composite one consisting of several columns, it should
return the array of the key column names.
```

EDIT: In the end I added the following to my Plugin file, and that seemed to do the trick:

```
public function onAfterInstall()
{
  craft()->db->createCommand()->dropColumn('myplugin_merchant_order', 'id');
  craft()->db->createCommand()->addPrimaryKey('myplugin_merchant_order', ['merchant_id', 'order_id']);
}
```

I also had to add this to my Record, to stop the validation failing because I'd removed the `id` column in the above step:

```
public function primaryKey()
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd consider that a bug since it works in Yii (see here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#defining-ar-class).  Will look into fixing it.